# Commercial RDF Visualization tool?

Tags: visualization, rdf, semantics, ontology, graph-visualization

I was wondering if anybody is aware of a commercial RDF Visualization Tool?

There are a number of posts on SO about RDF visualization tools, but most of them seem to be open source projects.

Comment: Well, I could *sell* you a copy of an open source tool you like. … *Why* is it required to be "commercial"? You should probably add the reasons for that to your question, as "commercial" can be understood in many different ways.

Comment: I am asked to work on implementing an RDF visualization for our organization. I have found a number of different open source tools, which may work, but I have not found any commercial tools. I was wondering if any exist since Open Source products and commercial products each carry their own pros and cons. Some key characteristics often associated with a commercial products are a more robust development team and customer support. These are things which I would like to consider when pursuing a particular visualization approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few from the usual suspects:

- [Altova SemanticWorks 2012](http://www.bluechillies.com/download/51375.html)
- [Microsoft Silverlight PivotViewer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/29/silverlight-pivotviewer-now-available.aspx)
- [Adobe Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdd.html)
- [Adobe AIR](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/desktop-rss-with-adobe-air/6310679)
- [Sentences](http://www.sentences.com/)
- [Stardog](http://stardog.com/)

Comment: Thanks, these are avenues to look into.